# Using Tesseract on Heroku with Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, tesseract

I would like to add OCR capabilities to my Django app running on Heroku.  I suspect the easiest way is by using [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).  I've noticed that there are a number of python wrappers for Tesseract's API, but what is the best way to get Tesseract installed and running on Heroku?  Via a custom buildpack like  [heroku-buildpack-tesseract](https://github.com/marcolinux/heroku-buildpack-tesseract) maybe?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get tesseract running on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, I am running it now.

Comment: Can you tell me how you did it?

Comment: I use multi-buildpack and https://github.com/marcolinux/heroku-buildpack-libraries.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm in the midst of trying to do that. Do I really have to create my own vulcan server and all that? I was hoping I could just use someone else's build.

Comment: No need for Vulcan at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41371/discussion-between-peter-alfvin-and-erik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to capture some notes on the solution I arrived at here.

My `.buildpacks` file:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
https://github.com/clearideas/heroku-buildpack-ghostscript
https://github.com/marcolinux/heroku-buildpack-libraries
```

My `.buildpacks_bin_download` file:

```
tesseract-ocr https://s3.amazonaws.com/tesseract-ocr/heroku/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz 3.02 eng,spa
```

Here is the key piece of python that does the OCRing of pdf files:

```
        # Additional processing
        document_path = Path(str(document.attachment_file))

        if document_path.ext == '.pdf':
            working_path = Path('temp', document.directory)
            working_path.mkdir(parents=True)

            input_path = Path(working_path, name)
            input_path.write_file(document.attachment_file.read(), 'w')

            rb = ReadBot()

            args = [
                'VBEZ',
                # '-sDEVICE=tiffg4',
                '-sDEVICE=pnggray',
                '-dNOPAUSE',
                '-r600x600',
                '-sOutputFile=' + str(working_path) + '/page-%00d.png',
                str(input_path)
            ]

            ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
            image_paths = working_path.listdir(pattern='*.png')
            txt = ''

            for image_path in image_paths:
                ocrtext = rb.interpret(str(image_path))
                txt = txt + ocrtext

            document.notes = txt
            document.save()
            working_path.rmtree()
```

Comment: +1 for the help. Where'd you learn about the tesseract aws resource?

Comment: Not sure -- I hacked at this for a long time in late October.  It's running great now though.  Feel free to contact me directly if you get stuck.  There are some traps, but it works pretty well.

Comment: Do you also need to set the `BUILDPACK_URL` environment variable to `https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi`?

Comment: Yes, mine is set to `BUILDPACK_URL:               https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like https://github.com/marcolinux/heroku-buildpack-libraries is no longer available...

Answer (score 0):

## Heroku, Django and tesseract

This doc will walk you through setting up tesseract on Heroku (i'm using django)

## Steps

1) Add heroku-apt-buildpack using the command:

This is the stable version. See the source [repository](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt)

```sh
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
```

2) Add Aptfile to project directory

`

```sh
$ touch Aptfile
```

3) Add the folowing to the Aptfile

tesseract-ocr-eng is the English language file for tesseract.

```sh
tesseract-ocr
tesseract-ocr-eng
```

4) Get path to the data downloaded by the tesseract-ocr-eng package

We will use this path for the next step

```sh
$ heroku run bash
$ find -iname tessdata # this will give us the path we need
```

You can exit heroku shell now `exit`

5) Now set a heroku config variable named TESSDATA_PREFIX to path

Set a heroku config variable named TESSDATA_PREFIX  to the path returned from `find -iname tessdata` cmnd above

```sh
$ heroku config:set TESSDATA_PREFIX=./.apt/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata
```

Now set heroku set a heroku config variable named TESSDATA_PREFIX  to the path returned from find -iname tessdata

6) Push changes to heroku

Set a heroku config variable named TESSDATA_PREFIX  to the path returned from find -iname tessdata cmnd above

```sh
$ git push heroku master
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if it works for you.